# On what steps from ecology plan have Joe Biden's administration already made progress?

Tags: united-states, international-relations, climate-change, joe-biden, ecology

Ecology was one of the main [points](https://joebiden.com/climate-plan/) of Joe Biden's election campaign:

- Ensure the U.S. achieves a 100% clean energy economy and reaches net-zero emissions no later than 2050
- Build a stronger, more resilient nation
- Rally the rest of the world to meet the threat of climate change
- Stand up to the abuse of power by polluters who disproportionately harm communities of color and low-income communities
- Fulfill our obligation to workers and communities who powered our industrial revolution and subsequent decades of economic growth.

I've heard about US coming back into Paris climate agreement. What else has Biden done in terms of climate change?

Comment: The so-called green new deal legislative package is slowly making its way through the negotiation process in Congress. It will likely have EV credits, incentives for low-carbon power generation and storage, research funding for fuel cells and the like. I wouldn't hold my breath waiting for certain big technically-achievable moves in overall energy efficiency or decarbonization (e.g. increasing vehicle occupancy, mass transit, significant energy tax, nuclear power). Another issue is that many of the technologies lack a domestic industrial champion to lobby for them.

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with this question per se, but I think it’s a bit early to get any meaningful answer

Comment: Note for close voters: I don’t really think this has multiple questions, it asks one question, which is “What else has Biden done in terms of climate change?” Giving multiple examples is different from asking multiple questions